# Formatting numbers on an html table to send in an email using app script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, gmail

I am trying to send out an email in app script when a button is pressed. I want this email to have a data table on it with information as well. The issue I cannot figure out is how to format the numbers in the table. I want the numbers to be formatted to "0.0000" format with only 4 decimal places. I also would like the very large numbers to be in scientific notation. Below is the script I am using to send out the email. Is there a way to format the numbers on the table?

```js
function dataArc() {
var brewers = "lost@gmail.com"
var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
   var pc = sss.getSheetByName("Pitch Calculator");
   var pcb= pc.getRange("C12").getValue();
   var pcbn = pc.getRange("B12").getValue();
   var pcd = pc.getRange("A12").getValue();
   var pcds = new Date(pcd)
   var month = 1+pcds.getMonth();
   var day = pcds.getDate();
   var year = pcds.getFullYear();
   var date= month+"/"+day+"/"+year
   var label = pcb+" "+pcbn+" "+date
   var pdh =pc.getRange("C11:K11")
   var header = pdh.getValues()
   var pd=pc.getRange("C12:K12")
   var data = pd.getValues();
   var backgrounds = pd.getBackgrounds();
   var table = "<html><body><table border=1><tr></tr>";
   for (var i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
    heads = header[i];
      table = table + "<tr>";
    for (var u = 0; u < heads.length; u++) {
      table = table + `<td style="background-color:${backgrounds[i][u]}">` + heads[u] + "</td>"; 
    }}
  
    table = table + "</tr>"
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    cells = data[i];

    table = table + "<tr>";
    for (var u = 0; u < cells.length; u++) {
      table = table + `<td style="background-color:${backgrounds[i][u]}">` + cells[u] + "</td>"; 
    }
    table = table + "</tr>"
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:brewers,
    subject:"Pitch Amount "+label,
    htmlBody: "Please pitch the amount of yeast in red below"+'\n'+table});
  }

}
```

This is what the email looks like when it is sent. As you can see there is 10ish decimals after the decimal place and the large numbers are in the millions and would be better visually if it was in scientific notation.
[email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fui56.jpg)

Comment: [Number.toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)